# Implementing a function to access an object's property versus accessing the property using dot notation, or bracket notation?

Tags: javascript

Reviewing some 3rd party code, I have found a function written to get a property of an object.

```
function getObjectProperty (obj, propertyName) {
        var o;
        if (obj) {
            o = obj[propertyName];
            if (o != null) {
                if (typeof o == 'function') return o();
            }
        }
        return o;
    }
```

An example how this function is called is:

```
var foo = getObjectProperty(r, 'objProp')
```

Is there some benefit to using this custom function to fetch the property, rather than just doing this:

```
var foo = r.objProp
```

or

```
var foo = r['objProp']
```

I just don't understand the benefit of using this function, if there is one? I could not find another example of this function, so I can only assume that it was custom made for this application. The only thing I can see is that it returns a function call if the object property is a function, but even then you could just write:

```
var foo = r.objProp()
```

Comment: The difference with your function is that it will unwrap the value if it's a function (by calling it)

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're right. It just simplifies getting values from functions if you don't want to use the function calling syntax yourself. Maybe it was written before [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) were readily available or is supposed to be backwards compatible with browsers that don't support them.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I know "code explanation" questions like this aren't normally welcomed, but I just couldn't understand why this was done.

Comment: @AlexChance I think looking at the ways it's used within your code would be more revealing than the code for the function itself. Maybe looking at those would provide some inside into _why_ the writer felt it would be useful to have such a function.

Comment: And I also just realized how obnoxiously long my post title was. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple difference. If given an object like:

```
var foo = { a: "a", b: function() { return "b" } }
```

Then `foo.b` or `foo[b]` gives a different result to `getObjectProperty(foo,"b")`

It appears to be a utility function to get a property and if it's a "getter" function, automatically call it. Getters are fairly recent and many older browsers don't support them (IE didn't get them until 9 I believe).

Of course, if the function assigned to `b` returned a function instead of a value, then it wouldn't unwrap, but presumably that wasn't the intention.

So why might this be useful? Because getters are useful. Imagine you had an object like this:

```
function order(quantity, price) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.unitPrice = price;
    this.totalPrice = function() { return this.quantity * this.unitPrice }
};

var myOrder = new order(10,2);
```

If I want to look at the properties of `myOrder` then I need to *know* as a consumer of this object that `totalPrice` is a function. If I use `getObjectProperty` instead, then I don't need to care about it. It will *do the right thing* and I don't need to worry about how it calculated `totalPrice`

Comment: Perhaps it was written for backwards compatibility then. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a (terribly named) utility function that, as you realized yourself, tries to get the value of the property from the object, but if that is a function, return the result of calling it.

Comment: So perhaps if there was an object where you did not know if the properties were functions or not, you could use this code to retrieve the standard property or the result of calling it?

Comment: @AlexChance - yes, but the name is terrible. It doesn't reveal what the function is really doing.

Comment: Yes, I agree. And of course, there are no comments to explain the true intention of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it obvious from the code?

This line invokes if the property is a function:

```
   if (typeof o == 'function') return o();
```

Although it doesn't get the property and the function doesn't do what it is supposed to.
`getObjectPropertyButIfFunctionInvokeInstead()` more suitable name.

It is poorly written code

Comment: From OP: "The only thing I can see is that it returns a function call if the object property is a function" so I think they're aware of that bonus. They're asking is there a good reason for someone to write this.